# Scale irregular multidimensional dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, scale

I have a dataframe like the one in the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'a1': [40, 0, 40, 100, 80],
        'a2': [[0, 2], [4, 5], [10, 2], [3, 8], [0, 0]],
        'a3': [[10, 2], [10, 0, 4], [1, 0, 1, 1], [-10, 6], [0, 2]],
        'a4': [-1, -0.08, 0.4, 1, 0.2],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
    a1       a2            a3    a4
0   40   [0, 2]       [10, 2] -1.00
1    0   [4, 5]    [10, 0, 4] -0.08
2   40  [10, 2]  [1, 0, 1, 1]  0.40
3  100   [3, 8]      [-10, 6]  1.00
4   80   [0, 0]        [0, 2]  0.20
```

and I would like to scale it to [0, 1] and also save the scalers, so that I can apply them on another dataset.
The resulting dataframe should look like:

```
scaled_df
    a1          a2                       a3    a4
0  0.4    [0, 0.2]                 [1, 0.6]  0.00
1  0.0  [0.4, 0.5]            [1, 0.5, 0.7]  0.46
2  0.4    [1, 0.2]  [0.55, 0.5, 0.55, 0.55]  0.70
3  1.0  [0.3, 0.8]                 [0, 0.8]  1.00
4  0.8      [0, 0]               [0.5, 0.6]  0.60
```

With dataframes without nested lists, I've been using [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler) this way:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
df1 = df[['a1', 'a4']]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(df1)
scaled_df = scaler.transform(df1)
dump(scaler, open('scaler.pkl', 'wb'))

scaler = load(open('scaler.pkl', 'rb'))
scaled_df2 = scaler.transform(df2)
```

but this is not working on the whole original df with nested lists.
I can think about some "hacky" approaches such as for each column, concatenate its rows in one array, calculate the scalar, store it in an array of scalars and apply it to the second dataframe, but I was wondering if there is a better, cleaner approach to do this.
Any ideas?

Comment: How do you ideally want to handle the elements of the lists with varying length? E.g. how exactly do you want to scale `a3` where you have to deal with third row (index 2) where you don't have a corresponding 4th column of values?

Comment: Ideally the resulting dataframe should maintain the same shape (I added scaled_df in the example). This is because the data will be fed to an algorithm that doesn't handle NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You could go through each of the feature columns, expand these to separate columns if they contain lists of values and then apply the `MinMaxScaler` to the expanded dataframe. Thus you can stick to using a single scaler object.

Try this:

```
frames = []
for feature in df.columns:
    if df[feature].dtype != "object":
        frames.append(df[feature])
        continue
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(df[feature].to_list(), index=df.index)
    tmp.columns = [f"{feature}_{x}" for x in range(tmp.shape[1])]
    frames.append(tmp)
    
df_exploded = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)

sc = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_data = sc.fit_transform(df_expanded)
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaled_data, columns=df_expanded.columns)
display(df_scaled)
```

Result:

```
    a1      a2_0    a2_1    a3_0    a3_1        a3_2    a3_3    a4
0   0.4     0.0     0.250   1.00    0.333333    NaN     NaN     0.00
1   0.0     0.4     0.625   1.00    0.000000    1.0     NaN     0.46
2   0.4     1.0     0.250   0.55    0.000000    0.0     0.0     0.70
3   1.0     0.3     1.000   0.00    1.000000    NaN     NaN     1.00
4   0.8     0.0     0.000   0.50    0.333333    NaN     NaN     0.60
```